# Ignoring specific file path during Format.Js message extraction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, formatjs

When using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) and TypeScript, a file is auto-generated in the `src` directory: `react-app-env.d.ts`. This file seems necessary to support image imports as discussed here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6560.

When using [Format.JS](https://formatjs.io/), I extract messages using the following command:

```
yarn extract 'src/**/*.ts*' --out-file lang/en-GB.json --id-interpolation-pattern '[sha512:contenthash:base64:6]'
```

But unfortunately this results in this error:

```
warning Error: Error processing file src/react-app-env.d.ts
Debug Failure. Output generation failed
Done in 9.64s.
```

I need to process both .ts and .tsx files. I have tried to hack the search pattern to exclude the specific file name, but I am now completely stumped as I am unsure of its precise specification.

As a workaround I can delete the file prior to extraction, but this is very annoying!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `'src/**/!(*.d).ts*'` pattern in your extract script, this will exclude all .d.* files from your src folder.

Comment: Many thanks, just helped me sort a very annoying issue. I only got it to work by changing your `{ts,tsx}` for `ts*` so have edited you answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do `formatjs extract --ignore='**/*.d.ts'`.

This is a good search https://github.com/search?l=JSON&q=%22formatjs+extract%22&type=Code if you're curious about usages.

I threw in a PR to update the documentation.